# zip argument #1 must support iteration on class object list

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a point class in python (Python36-32)

```
class point:
    def __init__(self , xPoint ,yPoint):
        self.x = xPoint
        self.y = yPoint

    def makeMeStr(self):
        return "("+str(self.x)+","+str(self.y)+")"

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.makeMeStr() 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.makeMeStr()
```

when i create a list of these points and when I do

```
left, right = zip(*myListOfPoint)
```

i get

```
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

Any suggestion please

Comment: The error says it should be a list or something that supports iteration

Comment: how can point class support iteration . It has 2  doubles , x and y

Comment: No, not the class, zip expects an iterator

Comment: myListOfPoint is a list which by default supports iteration  .

Comment: @Sayse it then says ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) . by deafult list must have * thats why i used that

Comment: A list supports iteration. But you're not zipping `myListOfPoints`, you're zipping `*myListOfPoints`. That `*` unpacks the list into a bunch of separate arguments to `zip`. So it's telling you that _the elements in the list that you're unpacking_ are not iterable, not that the list is not iterable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To support iteration add `__iter__()` method to your class (that method will yield x and y values from `point`):

```
class point:
    def __init__(self , xPoint ,yPoint):
        self.x = xPoint
        self.y = yPoint

    def makeMeStr(self):
        return "("+str(self.x)+","+str(self.y)+")"

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.makeMeStr()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.makeMeStr()

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y


list_of_points = [point(1, 2), point(3, 4), point(5, 6)]

left, right = zip(*list_of_points)
print(left)  # this will print all x values
print(right) # this will print all y values
```

Will print:

```
(1, 3, 5)
(2, 4, 6)
```